# One Server, Multiple Websites from a different PC

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, lamp

In my local network I have a ubuntu server (I can get to it via http://server)
I have lamp all set up ready to go, and have made a couple of websites, which I can access when I'm using the server itself by going to:

http://localhost.test1.com and http://localhost.test2.com

On the main machine I want to access these sites from I've edited the hosts file to forward those URLS to server

```
server localhost.test1.com
server localhost.test2.com
```

This sends my request to the server, but the server just serves up the default website.

Wham am I missing? How do I force apache to know which site I'm trying to get to?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/65199/is-it-possible-to-alias-a-hostname-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a virtual server for each site in apache's configuration `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. You do this by creating a new file conf file for each server, I would just must make copies of the default configuration. Then in each file you need to make the modifications in beginning of the file.

Default file:

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

You will need to change the virtualhost information and the documentRoot for each one.

example

```
    <VirtualHost localhost.test1.com:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo/test1
```

Finally you'll need to enable of these new sites

```
    sudo a2ensite test1
```

note: the site name is based on the name of the conf file.